# How do you prevent the "tree" command from listing the path?

Tags: batch-file

I am coding in batch. (.bat)

I am working on a project where I want to add in a high score at the end of the game. For the game to know the score, I have made it so that the batch file makes a folder at one point. The high score page then uses the **"tree"** command to list the high scores. It looks something like this...

```
@echo off
:high scores
echo High Scores
tree
pause >nul
goto end
```

I want when the **"tree"** command is said, the batch file does not echo the folder path, but only the files and folders. It looks like this:

```
Folder Path listing for volume (Volume Name)
Volume serial number is (Serial Number)
H:.
-----hs19
```

I just want the files and folders to be displayed, but don't know how to do it. I have different approaches, but none of them work like trying `tree >nul`, but this only hid the command entirely.

Does anyone have any ideas or feedback on what I should do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to print out the contents of the `tree` command but skipping the first few lines that contains undesirable lines, skip em.

Assuming you want to skip the first 3 lines:

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%l in ('tree') do echo %%l
```